# Polymer iron-form - paper-button submission not working

Tags: php, polymer

I am trying to use the Polymer element Iron-Form to submit information into the `$_POST` array. However my submit button (a paper-button) - which should run the script to submit the form - does not seem to submit the form when pressed.

I'm new to Polymer and to PHP, so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

**Form script**

```
<form is="iron-form" method="post" id="insert-project-form" action="/form/handler">
   <paper-input label="Project Title" name="title"></paper-input>
   <paper-input label="Client ID" name="clientid"></paper-input>
   <paper-input label="Working Hours" name="workhours"></paper-input>

   <paper-button raised onclick="submitForm()">Submit</paper-button>

   <script>
   function submitForm() {
   document.getElementById('insert-project-form').submit();
   }
   </script>
</form>
```

Comment: have u debugged the submit expression?

Comment: I have similar case and get Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem, and have been doing it the same way you do it. According to the [Documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form) it should work. But I have found a work around for this problem

Add a normal button for the submission and style its visibility to hidden

```
<button type="submit" id="SubmitButton" name="submit" style="visibility:hidden;"></button>
```

And in your javascript code change the submitForm function to this

```
function submitForm(){
document.getElementById('SubmitButton').click();
console.log("Submitted!")
}
```

And keep the paper button line the way it is.

```
 <paper-button raised onclick="submitForm()">Submit</paper-button>
```

What it does is when the paper button is clicked, it triggers a click event on the normal submit. I'm pretty sure there are more efficient ways than this, but I will be using this for now.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form is="iron-form" method="post" id="insert-project-form" action="/form/handler">
```

the attribute at the very end "action" needs to pass it to your php file. Assuming your php file is in a folder called "php". the solution to this would be

```
<form is="iron-form" method="post" id="insert-project-form" action="php/yourphpfile.php">
```

and your logic would be contained in the php file that submits it to a database if needed.